# How is an autoparallel equation related to Newton's second axiom?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I am currently working through [*The International Winter School on Gravity and Light*](https://www.youtube.com/@thewe-heraeusinternational2060) lecture series and have had some trouble understanding the following claim made in lecture $9$ at the [22:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBlCu1zgD4Y&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=10) minute mark.

Dr. Schuller says that asking

> "$(1)$ Can gravity be encoded in the curvature of space, such that its effects show if particles under the influence of (no other) force are postulated to move along straight lines in this curved space?"

is the same as asking:

> "$(2)$ Is $$\ddot{x}^{\alpha}(t)-f^{\alpha}(x(t)) = 0$$ of the form of a autoparallel equation?"

Note $\ddot{x}^{\alpha}$ is the ($\alpha^{th}$-component of the) acceleration of the test particle and $f^{\alpha}$ is the ($\alpha^{th}$-component of the) gravitational acceleration.

**My question is:**

why is asking question $(1)$ the same as asking question $(2)$? How is an autoparallel equation (an equation of the form $\ddot{x}^{\alpha}(t) + \dot{x}^{\beta}(t)\dot{x}^{\gamma}(t)\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}(x(t))$) related to question $(1)$?

Ironically, I understand the answer to this question from a mathematics point of view which is a resounding "no", you need to ask this question about *spacetime* not just *space*, but I'm just trying to connect the dots. Here is [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396859/) on this lecture and time stamp posted on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if a curve satisfies the autoparallel equation (2), then that is literally the meaning of the ‘straightest possible curves’ (relative to the given connection $\nabla$ whose autoparallels we’re discussing). If you have a curve $\gamma$ not obeying the autoparallel, but rather having some RHS $m\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=F\circ\gamma$, then you would interpret this as the particle undergoing motion with $F$ as the force field it is moving under.

Comment: ^ the utlimate thing is we want a mathematical structure to single out a particular collection of curves (worldlines) which we can call *inertial*. A linear connection $\nabla$ on the tangent bundle does this job perfectly (among other things). And the reason why we make such a ‘structural choice’ is because gravity is supposed to affect everything (massive and massless particles), which is why we model it as a ‘structure’ on the underlying manifold. This is unlike the electromagnetic field which only affects certain types of particles.

Comment: @peek-a-boo - I think I'm starting to get the point here, allow me to run through my thought process to ensure I am: We're trying to model gravity as the curvature of *space* and in doing so we would like to try to prove question (1) with the "gravity as a force point of view" which leads us to writing Newton's second law as $\ddot{x}^{\alpha}(t)-f^{\alpha}(x(t)) = 0$, which tells us the acceleration of a particle (subjected to a gravitational field) is equal to the gravitational acceleration of the field...

Comment: ...However, this equation is not an autoparallel equation (which tells us the condition for a straight line is that the acceleration along the line vanishes) and hence does not allow us to recover a connection from the $\Gamma$s, and in turn determine curvature. Is this the right idea?

Comment: Yup, as written these equations cannot (barring some trivial edge cases) be interpreted as an autoparallel equation of some connection. If we enlarge to a larger manifold, then we can, i.e in 4D *spacetime*, things work.

Comment: Btw, this idea of introducing a connection, as a way of prescribing a collection of curves, is not special to GR. You *can* discuss Newtonian mechanics in this way as well. See Penrose’s book for more details (for which [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/769935/203278) is an answer where I talk about some similar stuff for pre-Einstein spacetimes).

Comment: @peek-a-boo - Wonderful! Thank you very much for answering my questions and providing further readings, to which I'll take a look at now. Your help is always appreciated!

Comment: @peek-a-boo - Hi good morning, quick follow up question regarding the *worldline* of a particle: this lecture, Dr. Schuller defines the worldline of a particle given by the map (where $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$) $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $X(t) = (t, x^{1}(t), x^{2}(t), x^{3}(t)) := (X^{0}(t), X^{1}(t), X^{2}(t), X^{3}(t))$ however, I'm not quite understanding why he then says later that $X^{0}(\lambda) = (x^{0} \circ X)(\lambda)$; why can we define $X^{0}$ in this way?

Comment: First $x$ was used to denote a curve in $\Bbb{R}^3$, then later he most likely means a chart on $\Bbb{R}^4$. You should just replay the relevant sections.